# How to create photo effect like Under the skin

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask

I'm want create photo-effect like this
I'm guess it 2 layer blend or mask with the subject(woman) and forest
but how I re-create it in Photoshop

Thanks
[image: under the skin]

Comment: I'm just put the woman on top layer and set multiply 10-20% but the result come out not good enough

Answer (score 0):

I think you kind of answered your own question there.

Most likely you'd have one layer with the woman lying down and one with the forest shot. The forest layer should be beneath the one with the woman.

Then you can choose a variety of different approaches, but the easiest one ought to be to simply create a mask for the layer with the woman, invert it so that nothing shows through and then use a very soft brush to make her appear over the forest shot. You might want to lower the opacity of the layer with the woman just a little bit as well so that some of the forest still shows through. Or you could just lower the opacity of the brush before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the 3rd layer. Lower the flow of your brush and opacity if you like, although the lowered flow alone should be enough, and just paint back in the parts of the forest you want to show over the woman